# Unable to Import Custom image using IBM cloud Object storage(VMDK) through Softlayer Rest API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to import image from VMDK uploaded in Cloud Object Storage through Rest API, but getting the error as mentioned below.

Please help me in over coming this problem.

API used:
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createFromIcos

'BODY

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "jagaIBMcliTest",
            "bootMode": "HVM",
            "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "WIN_2012-STD-R2_64",
            "cloudInit": false,
            "ibmAccessKey": "<AccessKey>",
            "ibmSecretKey": "<SecretKe>",
            "ibmApiKey": "<ibmApiKey>",
            "uri": "cos://us-east/migrationbucket/WIN-TBTP9UG0SLB.vmdk",
            "isEncrypted": false
        }
    ]
}'
```

API Response:

```
{"error":"Not able to import from SL COS in Commercial environment unless account has ALLOW_INTERNAL_SWIFT_TO_COS_MIGRATE attribute","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

Comment: It seems the account requires additional permissions, I recommend you submit a ticket to SoftLayer, they could provide you further assistance about this error

Answer (score 0):

Only IBM Cloud console COS is supported for custom image management.
See here to upload image to IBM Cloud console COS and then import it.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/image-templates?topic=image-templates-preparing-and-importing-images#upload-to-ibm-cos

Comment: Thanks for reply Lifemikey. Is it possible only Importing an Image from IBM Cloud Object Storage using IBM Cloud Console?  If Possible to java please send link.

Comment: You can use the SoftLayer API Python Client to import images from IBM Cloud Object Storage
see here
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/speed-up-image-imports-to-ibm-cloud-infrastructure